# Thread does not run fast enough when other applications are running

Tags: python, python-multiprocessing, python-multithreading

I am using the threading module to run a function in the background while the rest of my script executes. The threaded function contains a for loop which waits for external 5 volt triggers, occuring every 15 ms, before continuing to the next loop iteration.

When this code is the only thing running on the PC, everything works as expected. However when I run other necessary applications, putting strain on the cpu, the For loop in the threaded function only executes and continues to the next iteration within the 15 ms time window about 90% of the time.

The input to the threaded function is a list of ctypes pointers.

I am running the threaded function from within a class, so using multiprocessing is tricky (if that would help at all i'm not sure).

I've tried to illustrate the problem below with a skeleton of the two classes

```
import ctypes
import Write_transient_frames_func
import SendScriptCommands
from threading import Thread

class SlmInterface():

    def __init__(self,sdk):

        self.sdk = sdk

    def precalculate_masks(self, mask_list):

        '''takes input mask_list, a list of numpy arrays containing phase masks
           outputs pointers to memory location of masks
        '''

        #list of pointers to locations of phase mask arrays in memory 
        mask_pointers = [mask.ctypes.data_as(POINTER(c_ubyte)) for mask in mask_list]

        return mask_pointers

    def load_precalculated_triggered(self, mask_pointers):

        okay = True
        print('Ready to trigger')

        for arr in mask_pointers:

            okay = self.Write_transient_frames_func(self.sdk, c_int(1), arr, c_bool(1), c_bool(1), c_uint(0))

        assert okay, 'Failed to write frames to board'      
        print('completed trigger sequence')


class Experiment():

    def run_experiment(self, sdk, mask_list):  

        slm = SlmInterface(sdk)

        #list of ctypes pointers      
        mask_pointers = slm.precalculate_masks(mask_list)

        ##the threaded function
        slm_thread = Thread(target=slm.load_precalculated_triggered, args = [mask_pointers])
        slm_thread.start()

        time.sleep(0.1)

        # this function loads the 15ms trigger sequences to the hardware and begins the sequence 
        self.mp_output = SendScriptCommands()
```

Is it possible to speed up execution of the threaded function? Would parallel processing help? Or am i fundamentally limited by my cpu?

Comment: You are using parallel processing.  Threads are under the control of the operating system.  I think your requirement of 15 ms response time is unrealistic.

Comment: Thanks, is there an alternative that would allow me to run the load_precalculated_triggered function in the background and then continue with the rest of the script?

Comment: I had the same problem before and found out that my threads has while loops running and eat up cpu power, later i found out that i have to add ‘time.sleep(0.1)’ as a delay time inside the loops to give time to another threads to work, and surprisingly my cpu usage is in normal and threads running super fast, note: my application is a download manager which generates 100+ concurrent threads in one download and can start concurrent downloads in same time without speed drop

Comment: Sleeping by 100 ms in a thread that is trying to catch signals that happen every 15 ms is only going to make the problem worse. Now you are missing ~5 signals every 6 - great job!

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, Python will likely not be able to do much better. Python has a [global interpreter lock](https://wiki.python.org/moin/GlobalInterpreterLock), which means that multithreading doesn't work the way it does in other languages.

Answer (score 1):

You should be aware of the fact that multithreading in python makes the application run slower. The good alternative is using asyncio, because it allows cooperative multitasking of several tasks within one thread (-> the os doesn't need to actually switch a thread -> less overhead -> faster execution). If you havn't used that before it's kind of weired to use at first but it's actually really nice.

However, your task really seems to be cpu bound. So maybe the only option is multiprocessing in python.

Answer (score 1):

Probably Python isn't really the culprit here. The point is, with general purpose, preemptive, multiuser operating systems you are not going to get the guarantee of running continuatively enough to catch triggers any 15 ms. CPU is allocated in quanta of generally some tens of ms, and the OS can - and will - let your thread run more or less frequently depending on the CPU load, in an effort to give to each process its fair share of available CPU time.

You may increase the priority of your thread to ask for it to have the precedence over the others, or, in the extreme case, change it to real-time priority to let it hog the CPU indefinitely (and potentially hang the system if stuff goes awry).

But really, the actually solution is to handle this at lower level, either in kernel mode or in hardware. Polling at those rates from user mode is unadvisable if you cannot miss a signal, so you should probably investigate if your hardware/driver provides some higher level interface - for example, an interrupt (translated e.g. to unlocking some blocking call, or producing a signal or something) on trigger.